# How to read numpy array from disk line-by-line (row-by-row)?

Tags: python, arrays, file, numpy, io

I would like to do the following but reading in an array 1 row at a time.  These files do not have any header or index/row names...just floats.

```
f_1 = open("testing.tsv", "r")
f_2 = open("testing.tsv", "r")

for i, (f1_line, f2_line) in enumerate(zip(f_1.readlines(), f_2.readlines())):
    f1_line = list(map(float,f1_line.split("\t")))
    f2_line = list(map(float,f2_line.split("\t")))
    print(i, len(f1_line), len(f2_line))
    break
```

I can't figure out how to do this with `numpy` so I can read the rows as 1-dimensional `ndarrays` WITHOUT loading everything to disk.

```
# Psuedo code
f_1 = open("testing.tsv", "r")
f_2 = open("testing.tsv", "r")

for i, (f1_line, f2_line) in enumerate(zip(np.loadtxt(f_1), np.loadtxt(f_2))):
    print(i, len(f1_line), len(f2_line))
    break
```

**Can `np.loadtxt` be used in this way? If so, how? If not, what other way can `numpy` process files in this way?**

Comment: Why not `(np.fromstring(line, sep='\t') for line in f)`?

Comment: This is definitely faster than what I have above.  Are there any iterator file constructors in numpy?

Comment: `loadtxt` (and `genfromtxt`) reads a file line by line (also accepts a list of lines), and collected values in a list of lists.  At the end it construct the array from that list.

Comment: Is the fact that you are working with two files at a time significant?  Can't you just load them separately, and concatenate the resulting arrays?  Why line by line?

Comment: @hpaulj so can you iterate through `loadtxt` so it reads the file line-by-line instead of loading all the dat ain at once?

Comment: You don't iterate through a function!  You can read the file in chunks and feed the resulting lines to `loadtxt`. But you still haven't explained why you want to work line by line.  That would be slow way to work with a file.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "can `loadtxt` return an iterator without loading the entire array into memory.  The reason I want to work line-by-line is b/c I don't want to load all of the data in at once.  I have 2 files that are lined up where each row can be compared.  It seems that my two options are the `np.fromstring` and to load everythign into memory with `loadtxt`.

Comment: @O.rka `loadtxt` won't return an iterator (unless you build your own hacked copy). It reads chunks (that for well formed files should be one line) and dynamically grows the corresponding array.

Comment: `loadtxt` returns an array built from all the lines that you give it.  That should be clear enough from its documentation (or a few quick tests).   But for reading line by line, it's overkill.  Just read, split, and make the array from that list.

Comment: I'm aware that `loadtxt` doesn't return an iterator with default settings.  I was asking if there an option for it to do so or if there was anything available in `numpy` that allows for this functionality.  `np.fromstring` is the closest to what I was looking for.